# particular key value from a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I am interested only to know the value of key "DelayedAutoStart" and expect this code to work, but it print much more information. Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

```
   use Win32::Registry;
   use Data::Dumper;
   $p = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion";
   $p = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\sppsvc";
   $main::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Open($p, $CurrVer) || 
    die "Open: $!";
   $CurrVer->GetValues(\%vals); 
   #print Dumper(\%vals);

   foreach $k (keys %vals) {
   $key = $vals{$k};
   if ($$key[0] == "DelayedAutoStart")
   {
   print "$$key[0] = $$key[2]\n"; 
   }
}
```

RESULT:

```
ServiceSidType = 1
ErrorControl = 1
LaunchProtected = 1
DisplayName = @%SystemRoot%\system32\sppsvc.exe,-101
Start = 2
ImagePath = %SystemRoot%\system32\sppsvc.exe
Description = @%SystemRoot%\system32\sppsvc.exe,-100
DelayedAutoStart = 1
ObjectName = NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
RequiredPrivileges = SeAuditPrivilege SeChangeNotifyPrivilege         
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege SeImpersonatePrivilege
FailureActions = ÇQ☺         ♥   ¶   ☺   └È☺ ☺   Óô♦︎
DependOnService = RpcSs
Type = 16
```

Comment: Try after removing `print Dumper(\%vals);`

Comment: That is already commented but still it print much more.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have caught your problem

Answer (score 5):

Please add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code. They will give you an error telling you that you're using the wrong kind of comparison operator. The `==` equality operator is for comparing numbers not strings. You need `eq` which does a string comparison.

Also, you're confusing matters rather by storing a hash value in a variable called `$key` and generally making things far more complicated than they need to be!

```
foreach my $key (keys %vals) {

  if ($key eq "DelayedAutoStart")
  {
    print "$key = $vals{$key}[2]\n";
  }
}
```

But, of course, you can just look up the value in the hash directly. No need to iterate over the keys. That's pretty much the point of using a hash :-)

```
my $key = 'DelayedAutoStart';
if (exists $vals{$key}) {
  print "$vals{$key} = $vals{$key}[2]\n";
}
```